# Доброго времени суток. Прошу помощи с SQL Lite

Tags: sql, sqlite

Как новичок, тренируюсь на валидаторе https://sql-validator.ru/task/clients_applications
Никак не могу понять, почему мой запрос неправильный и не совпадает с правильным ответом

```
SELECT 
  CLIENT_ID,
  APPLICATION_ID
from credit_applications
WHERE CLIENT_ID NOT IN (SELECT
          CLIENT_ID
          from credit_applications
           WHERE CLIENT_ID IS NOT NULL
          GROUP BY CLIENT_ID
          HAVING CREDIT_PRODUCT_TYPE = 7
);
```

Буду рад, если укажете, где я ошибся в коде и как правильно должен быть написан запрос.
Заранее спасибо

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос задание, под которое вы написали данный запрос

Comment: Выведите идентификаторы клиентов и идентификаторы заявок для тех клиентов, которые ни разу не оформляли кредитную карту (CREDIT_PRODUCT_TYPE = 7). Учитывайте, что в таблице могут встретиться записи, где идентификатор клиента неопределен (NULL). В выборке должны присутствовать два атрибута: CLIENT_ID, APPLICATION_ID.

Comment: Это в сам вопрос добавьте, нажав кнопку "Править" под вопросом

Comment: `having` не нужен, т.к. нет агрегирующей функции, следовало заменить на `where`в подзапросе.

Answer (score 1):

Для того, что бы отобрать идентификаторы клиентов, которые не подавали заявки на кредитные карты, подойдет вот такой запрос:

```
select 
  CLIENT_ID,
  APPLICATION_ID 
from credit_applications a
where a.client_id not in (
  select CLIENT_ID from credit_applications ac
  where ac.CREDIT_PRODUCT_TYPE = 7
  and ac.client_id is not null
);
```